# OpenCV 2.4.9 - Traincascade problems

Tags: c++, opencv

I use OSX 10.11. I'm new to opencv and I'm trying to train a simple (and surely weak) cascade classifier to detect an object. I have already read several answers, posts, guide, docs and tutorials about cascade classifier but I have some problems. I referred to this guide:

[guide](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html)

That follow opencv doc. Now I have 8 jpg with my interest object and 249 background images (I know that it's a poor dataset but it's only an attempt).

When I call opencv_createsamples I noticed the author of guide generate 1500 samples and also I do it. It means that generate 1500 samples from my 8 positive images?

```
perl bin/createsamples.pl positives.txt negatives.txt samples 1500 "opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 80 -h 40"
```

Note that in sample folder I have only 7 img*.jpg.vec file. They would not be 1500? After when I call:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

I have some errors because missing "OpenCL" "AppKit" "QuartzCore" "QTKit" "Cocoa". Where I can retrieve these? However I'm tried to continue and I generate samples.vec file.

```
find ./samples -name '*.vec' > samples.txt ./mergevec samples.txt samples.vec
```

Finally I train my classifier with this code:

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000 -numNeg 249 -featureType LBP -w 80 -h 40 -precalcValBufSize 2048 -precalcIdxBufSize 4096
```

After read some posts I've choosen -numPos smaller than 1500 samples previously generated (but where are they?). When I start the training, the one stuck in this situation:

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 0):

What I learnt when  I tried to follow the same (and other) tutorial:

- Yes, createsamples turns a single positive into many. The *.vec file contains many of them in one file. If you display the *.vec file using opencv_createsamples, you can page through them with arrow keys (I think).
- You need the mergevec program, it combines all *.vec files into one, which is needed for training. I'm using Windows, so I have no idea how to get the mac stuff.
- The output of the opencv_traincascade seems to indicate it found a thousand images in samples.vec. If you don't have mergevec, I assume you are using a prebuild samples.vec file.
- What do you mean by "stuck in this situation"? No more output, but no crash? Sometimes, training takes hours.